# How can I count the result of SQLite Query Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite, json.net

I want to get how many rows does my SQLite Query. The problem is my code cannot be **Deserialize** in order to get the total row count. I am using this as a login method in my application. There is an error in **"var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(userData);"**. The error is

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

```
var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
var conn = db.GetConnection();

var getCaf = conn.QueryAsync<CAFTable>("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserID=? AND UserPassword=?",Username,Password);
string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getCaf);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(userData);

if (result.Count < 1)
{
   MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Http", Username);
}
else
{
   Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MainMenu()), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using json here at all?  It is not needed.

`QueryAsync` should return a `List<T>`

```
var getCaf = await conn.QueryAsync<List<CAFTable>>("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserID=? AND UserPassword=?",Username,Password);
```

then just count the results

```
var count = getCaf.Count;
```

Comment: I just followed a tutorial there is no need to return a list

Comment: there is an error on var count = getCaf.Count(); the error is "does not contain for 'Count' accepting a first argument of type"

Comment: sorry, Count is a property, not a method.  Your query is returning a SET of rows, so it makes sense to map it to a List<T>.  If ALL you want is the count, there are ways to do that without selecting and returning all of the data.

Comment: I tried var result = getUser.Result.Count; and it worked